# KendoUI grid - date filter on server side - sending "Invalid date" with datetimepicker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have problem with filter on kendo grid.
When I have column with type date and filter defined as:

```
    "filterable": (field.code != "___createDate___" ? {
        ui: function(element) {
            element.kendoDateTimePicker({
                format: settingsService.getDateTimeFormat()
            })
        }
    }
```

in dataSource of grid in method parameterMap I'm geting filter date as "Invalid date"
How han I solve this problem ?

**EDIT**:

Somewhere I found that I need to use kendo.culture, I'm setting culture and than not solved problem.

Comment: What value returs the settingsService.getDateTimeFormat()?

Comment: settingsService.getDateTimeFormat() this returns string: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: even If I paste there string (without calling service method), still not works.

Comment: Just a guess but try to add this after format property:
`parseFormats: [kendo.culture().calendar.patterns.g]`.

Comment: j4ro - it dosn't help... I I can't still got it working...